# Как Вы оцениваете время необходимое для выполнения задачи?

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

В связи с экспериментом с выносом разговоров "за жизнь" на мету, решил задать и свои вопросы:

Каждому профессиональному разработчику приходится сталкиваться с оценкой времени на задачи.

Абсолютное большинство разработчиков (да и людей вообще) с этим справляются плохо и очень плохо. В этом виновато как устройство человеческих мозгов, так и предметная область:

[image: https://xkcd.com/1425/]

Понятно, что с набором опыта точность предсказаний повышается, но лично у меня она все равно ужасна.
Для себя я применяю пролетарский метод "10 минут подумай как будешь делать, а потом увеличь интуитивную оценку в несколько раз"

Какие практики Вы используете для того чтобы повысить точность своих предсказаний?
Сколько времени Вы обычно тратите на оценку как это делаете?
Пытаетесь ли дать оценку в точных человеко-часах или в каких-то сторипоинтах, которые в реальные часы превратит уже менеджер?

Отдельный слой сложности возникает когда надо оценить примерные сроки "за себя и за того парня".
То есть когда у тебя есть несколько подчиненные и надо примерно оценить что успеет команда.
Как Вы поступаете в этом случае?

Comment: Разбиваю задачи на фрагменты до тех пор, пока каждый из них не кажется простым и атомарным. Оцениваю время на каждый фрагмент.

Comment: А где об эксперименте выноса на Мету почитать?

Comment: @alexolut, это надо у Ника спрсоить: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35273038#35273038, я просто заметил что офтоп вопросы стали на мете появляться и плюсоваться и решил добавить)

Comment: @alexolut отчасти тут: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2423/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83

Comment: @Nofate по-моему, там ничего не сказано о возможности задавать новые вопросы подобного плана на Мете.

Comment: @alexolut, если Вы хотите закрыть оффтопиком, делайте это сейчас, пока у меня руки не дошли еще два подобных написать =D

Comment: @alexolut, я бы тоже предпочел какой-то явный мотивационный пост от Ника. С меткой [meta-tag:важное].

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму пишите, не стесняйтесь. Я один, а надо 5 для закрытия, если что :) Но я пока не голосую для прояснения ситуации. Всё как-то неоднозначно.

Comment: кстати, то, что описано в комиксе, делается через bing cognitive services минут за 15

Comment: @PashaPash, это потому что кто-то уже потратил на это 5 лет и исследовательскую команду) Там еще есть замечательный альт текст в самом комиксе, но я не нашел как его сюда нормально вставить

Comment: Скопипастю сюда альт текст к xkcd: "In the 60s, Marvin Minsky assigned a couple of undergrads to spend the summer programming a computer to use a camera to identify objects in a scene. He figured they'd have the problem solved by the end of the summer. Half a century later, we're still working on it."

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму по сабжу - декомпозиция, прошлый опыт, "колбаска" в Ганте на непредвиденные расходы, умножение срока задачи на 2, если есть интеграция со сторонней системой.

Answer (score 5):

Мозг человека - удивительная вещь. Важным его свойством является способность к тренировке.

Например: как вы оцениваете, с какой силой оттолкнуться, чтобы перепрыгнуть через лужу? Думаю, что вы не оцениваете силу ветра, расстояние, усталость, не умножаете это на π и не делите пополам. Просто раньше много раз прыгали, иногда попадали в лужу, иногда слишком далеко получалось, иногда точно. Так и научились оценивать.

С оценкой времени задач - то же самое. Оцениваете задачу, делаете, не угадали - в следующий раз оцениваете по-другому. Просто времени, чтобы научиться, нужно больше, ведь итерации гораздо длиннее: прыжок через лужу - одна попытка в 10 секунд, выполнение задачи - одна попытка в час, или день или неделю.

Для тренировки мозга достаточно осознанного наблюдения. Когда-то читал книгу по самоорганизации, не помню, как называется. Там была ситуация: человек учился водить машину, но постоянно превышал скорость. Автор сказал ему: просто наблюдай за скоростью, смотри на спидометр раз в 30 секунд. И со временем, просто наблюдая, ученик научился держать скорость в пределах разрешенной, не глядя на спидометр, а чувствуя ее.

Еще важный момент - мотивация. Если вам (лично вам, а не вашему руководителю) не важно, правильно вы оцените задачу или нет, то научиться будет сложно.

Моя мотивация такая - я считаю себестоимость своей работы в часах, умноженных на стоимость часа. А клиенту нужно заранее сказать итоговую цену. Если скажу мало, а работы получится больше - буду в убытке. Если скажу много, заказчик скажет "ой, что-то дорого", и заказа не будет.

Если вы работаете в компании, мотивация может быть другая, но похожая. Скажете мало - менеджер будет кричать, что сроки сорваны, скажете много - будет давить "а почему так долго".

А насчет тренировки и наблюдения - я использовал программу для тайм-трекинга. Начал заниматься задачей - включил таймер. Перерыв - выключил. Закончил - сложил все "подходы", вычислил себестоимость, записал в отчет. Отчет в конце месяца еще раз проанализировал, вычислил итоги по месяцу, выставил счета.

Первые 6 месяцев просто работал в таком режиме. Потом заметил, что могу оценить задачу в часах, причем довольно точно - до 20% погрешности. А самое интересное, что если не получалось оценить в часах, то тогда я оценивал в деньгах, делил на стоимость часа, и погрешность была примерно такой же.

Я думаю, это очень хороший результат - 20% погрешности. Но получился он не методом каких-то специальных тренировок, а сам собой - просто постоянно перед глазами задачи/часы/стоимости, и мозг сам начинает переводить одно в другое. Я не знаю, как он это делает, но получается довольно хорошо.

Иногда, конечно, можно что-то не предусмотреть и сильно ошибиться. Так бывает с задачами, которые раньше не делал, когда нет экспертизы. Система не идеальна. Но что делать, если не уложился в срок/стоимость, наверное, тема для другого вопроса.

Comment: Благодарю, чрезвычайно полезный ответ)

Answer (score 4):

Когда я только знакомился с веб-разработкой, эта проблема стояла особенно остро, потому что не было совершенно никакого опыта и понимания того, какие могут возникнуть технические сложности во время реализации проекта. Когда я немного подрос, поднакопил «жирка», столкнулся с достаточно большим спектром задач, то появилась другая проблема — я стал непреднамеренно занижать необходимое время, из-за чего процентов так в двадцати-тридцати случаев приходилось лепить уже что-нибудь, лишь бы успеть. А потом еще отдельную задачу на рефактор ставить.

Потом я стал выделять себе отдельное время на оценку задачи, час-другой ничего не решает, но точность предсказания уже выше. Ведь это достаточно просто: взять листик, отметить что надо будет реализовать до самых маленьких частей, примерно расставить время напротив каждой из частей и потом подбить сумму. Точность повысилась, но к 100%-ной так и не подошла.

Потом нашлось достаточно простое решение — завышать сроки. Надо сделать 3 блока, на который тратиться обычно по 2 часа, значит можно указать в оценке времени не 6, а 9 или даже 12 часов. Но тут возникает другая проблема — что делать с задачами, которые занимают не часы, а недели или месяцы? Делать проект месяц вместо полутора-двух недель ведь явно перебор. Ответ нашелся в [докладе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIFClfBXuIQ&feature=youtu.be) Вадима Макишвили (он, кстати, тоже рекомендует завышать сроки на небольшие задачи в 2-3 раза): завышайте сроки по формуле `первоначальная оценка * π / 2`. То есть, надо вам на проект 60 дней, скажите что за 94 дня управитесь и готово.

Comment: Кстати, опытный манагер в свою очередь умножит вашу оценку на 3, а конечный пользователь, общающийся с этим манагером в свою очередь умножает на 2. И тем не менее, в продукте, которым все ожидали пользоваться через год (после всех умножений)  еще пару лет вылезают разные ошибки (я даже не говорю, что функциональность минимум на треть не соответствует текущей документации)

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko  "То есть, надо вам на проект 60 дней, скажите что за 94 дня управитесь и готово." - А как вы можете узнать, что вам надо 60 дней на проект?! Допустим, вы назвали цифру 94 дня, как вы написали. А почему вы после этого не можете призадуматься, и к этой второй цифре не применить снова вашу формулу? Где тот критерий, что это - конечная итерация?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow в формуле содержится переменная `первоначальная оценка` — как её определить каждый себе ответит по-разному, наверное, я вот дроблю задачу на достаточно мелкие блоки, которые поддаются более-менее точной оценке. критерий, что это конечная итерация, состоит в том, чтобы применить эту формулу один раз. если результат надо корректировать, то делать это с первоначальной оценкой, а не с конечным результатом.